# Given a Geopandas GeoDataFrame with several geometry columns: How to calculate the distances to a main geometry column?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely

To make my problem comprehensible, I first build two simple GeoDataFrames with one column each for the point geometries, and extend the first one by as many columns as there are in the second one, and fill it with the corresponding values of the second one.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"geometry":["POINT (4601713.002 3161641.211)",
                 "POINT (4596192.207 3241423.174)",
                 "POINT (4572005.011 3257270.689)"]})
df_1['geometry'] = df_1['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf_1 = gp.GeoDataFrame(df_1,
                        geometry="geometry",
                        crs={'init': 'epsg:' + str(3035)})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'geometry':["POINT (4627355.438 3211988.792)",
                 "POINT (4599267.641 3220442.514)",
                 "POINT (4557279.752 3237223.279)"]})
df_2['geometry'] = df_2['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf_2 = gp.GeoDataFrame(df_2, 
                        geometry="geometry",
                        crs={'init': 'epsg:' + str(3035)})

gdf_2 = gdf_2.assign(Name = lambda x: 'gdf2_' + (gdf_2.index.astype(str)))
gdf_1 = gdf_1.assign(**dict.fromkeys(gdf_2.Name))

# Loop through df_1:
columnsOfInterest = gdf_1.columns[gdf_1.columns.str.startswith("gdf2_")]

for i in columnsOfInterest:
    # get the geometry from gdf_1: (works!)
    gdf_1[i]= list(gdf_1[columnsOfInterest==i].geometry)*len(gdf_1)
gdf_1
```

[DataFrame_gdf_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KruKr.png)

Now I have problems with the distance calculation. Since I have a lot of point data in my original datasets, I need a solution that allows me to calculate the distances all in one step. What I tried so far is to loop through the new columns of df_1, but the distance calculation seems to not work on a Series. I get the AttributeError: "'Series' object has no attribute 'distance'").

```
# Loop through df_1:
columnsOfInterest = gdf_1.columns[gdf_1.columns.str.startswith("gdf2_")]

for i in columnsOfInterest:
    # get the geometry from gdf_1: (works!)
    gdf_1[i]= list(gdf_1[columnsOfInterest==i].geometry)*len(gdf_1)
    # distance calculation: (does not work!)
    gdf_1[i]=gdf_1[i].distance(gdf_1.geometry)
gdf_1
```

Does anyone know a solution to the problem?

Comment: Can you add sample of the dataframe?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question! So, the first codeblock I posted to rebuild a simple version of the dataframe I want to work with (gdf_1). I added a picture now as well.

Comment: You have a few problems in your code, I'm not near a computer right now, so I'll be able to post code tomorrow. In the meantime, check out the vincenty package, which contains a method to calculate a distance between two geo locations.

Comment: The frame has the main geometry row "geometry" and 3 other geometry rows that are derived from another dataframe and all start with "gdf2_". Now,  I want to override all of the row values in the columns starting with "gdf2_" with a distance calculation between their own values and the values in "geometry".

Comment: Vincenty seems to be a very interesting package. Is it correct that you see it as the solution for my problem, because it does not refer to the shapely geometries and I simply work with hashable float data in a list? On the other hand it seems that vincenty does not accept metric geometry data for the distance calculation, does it? The strength of the package lies in a millimetre-precise calculation, which I don't necessarily need, but that wouldn't be a disadvantage either.

Comment: What's the endgame with the data here? Map plotting?

Comment: Nope, I am building an agent model in which I have located agents at certain starting points (the main geometries). For each agent I would like to have the distance to all possible endpoints (values from the 2nd data frame) available. Later, the distance is an important decision criterion for my agents to decide to visit an endpoint. In short, I just need the table with the distance values, no graphics :)

Comment: I just got an idea that is not very neat but functional and avoids the problem with Shapely geometry data that cannot be iterated. I rearranged the data set so that all the data of the original gdf_2 is in one column. Then I created a new column and stored the result of the distance calculations in it. Afterwards I unraveled the data set into its many columns again. It works. I'm just curious how long the whole procedure takes for a data set with very many rows and columns...

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [c for c in gdf_1 if c.startswith('gdf2_')]
gdf1_melted = pd.melt(gdf_1, id_vars=['geometry','Name'], value_vars=keys, value_name='TargetPointCoo')

gdf1_melted['dist_km'] = gdf1_melted.apply(lambda r: round(r['geometry'].distance(r['TargetPointCoo'])/1000,1), axis=1)
gdf1_melted.drop('TargetPointCoo', axis=1, inplace=True)  

pivoted = gdf1_melted.pivot(index = "Name", columns = "variable", values = "dist_km").reset_index()
pivoted

joined = pivoted.join(copyFromPreviousGdf_1.set_index('Name'), on='Name')
print(joined)
```